# How to read detection responses into a CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv, image-processing, computer-vision, tracking

I am dealing with tracking in MATLAB and using datasets that provide detection responses in a text file.

I am trying to read this file and save it in a CSV file, then deal with the CSV file for processing.

The text file information is not ordered line by line and there are two text files in the datasets. One of them has a name "gt.txt" and another is called "det.txt".

A sample of the text file is shown (comma-delimited):

```
1,-1,198,203,62.22,141.19,42.848,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,140,272,36.769,83.436,41.154,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,396,178,104,236,35.498,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,160,252,47.893,108.68,34.648,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,54,264,74.286,168.57,23.007,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,166,201,52,118,15.845,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,277,188,86.667,196.67,15.655,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,198,203,62.22,141.19,55.025,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,134,196,74.286,168.57,45.498,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,412,178,104,236,38.049,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,48,174,112.01,254.17,34.822,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,275,222,62.22,141.19,29.457,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,157,184,74.286,168.57,0.086108,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,152,272,40,90.769,46.466,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,255,198,80,181.54,44.237,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,428,178,104,236,42.217,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,175,252,47.893,108.68,32.099,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,62,321,52,118,17.375,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,208,202,56.877,129.07,13.465,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,134,167,40,90.769,12.379,-1,-1,-1
3,-1,174,201,52,118,6.7745,-1,-1,-1
4,-1,250,188,86.667,196.67,51.231,-1,-1,-1
4,-1,146,196,74.286,168.57,48.567,-1,-1,-1
4,-1,428,178,104,236,40.005,-1,-1,-1
4,-1,53,156,125.53,284.85,27.227,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,157,196,74.286,168.57,45.902,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,486,297,52,118,45.846,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,263,274,47.893,108.68,42.095,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,214,253,40,90.769,25.063,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,146,167,40,90.769,17.37,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,94,249,52,118,16.452,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,70,321,52,118,14.368,-1,-1,-1
5,-1,454,219,74.286,168.57,13.63,-1,-1,-1
```

Comment: I don't understand how your csv file should look in the end. How many columns should it have? Which values should go into the first column?

Comment: Maybe the question should be titled "How to white detected responses into CSV?" I cannot understand your question. Maybe you can elaborate your process so we can provide better opinion?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is your "csv-file" is comma seperated, but new lines are defined by spaces?

```
fid=fopen('det.txt','rt');
str=fread(fid,inf,'uint8=>char')
result = cell2mat(textscan(str,'%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f '))
csvwrite('result.txt',result);
```